# Pandas - handling NaN

Tags: python, pandas

In a dataframe like this:

```
df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'Player':['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
                                'Goals':[1, NaN, 1],
                                'Assists':[2, NaN, 1],
                                'ShotBar':[NaN 1, NaN],
                                'ShotDefended':[NaN, 1, NaN],
                                'ShotOut':[3, 2, NaN]})
```

How can I replace all `NaN` with 1, and add 1 to all other cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].fillna(0).add(1)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].add(1).fillna(1)
```

Output:

```
  Player  Goals  Assists  ShotBar  ShotDefended  ShotOut
0    One    2.0      3.0      1.0           1.0      4.0
1    Two    1.0      1.0      2.0           2.0      3.0
2  Three    2.0      2.0      1.0           1.0      1.0
```

---

**Update**: to work  on numeric columns only:

```
num_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns
df[num_cols] = df[num_cols].fillna(0).add(1)
```

Comment: I need to fill NaN with 1.

Comment: `.add(1)` will turn those `0` in `NaN` into `1`.

Comment: but I need to turn `NaN` into 1 AND add 1 to all cells that were 1 or above. is that what your solution does?

Comment: My code does exactly **replace all NaN with 1, and add 1 to all other cells**  as showned in the output.

Comment: thank you. my example was only a dummy df. can your solution provide an obs for numeric types, only? because if I apply that to real df, I get `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`, since there are strings in some columns

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this:
First replace all `NaN` with zeros and then add 1:

```py
df = df.fillna(0)
df[df.columns[1:]]+=1 #skipping the first columns with str
```

Else you can also first add elements with 1 and then replace `NaN` with 1:

```py
df[df.columns[1:]]+=1
df = df.fillna(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
num_cols = df_temp.select_dtypes('number').columns
df_temp[num_cols] = df_temp[num_cols].add(1, fill_value=0)
```